# Register a notification observer for a class outside that class

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I want to register a notification observer outside of the class that is observing the notification reception.

i tried to do it like this :

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
       addObserver:[ViewController class]  
       selector:@selector(NotificationReceived:) 
       name:@"notification" object:nil];
```

however, this forces me to make the method NotificationReceived in ViewController class to be `+(void)` instead of `-(void)` like i want it to be

is there a way to register the ViewController as a notification observer outside the ViewController class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create an instance of that class and keep it alive in memory, something like:

```
UIViewController *myViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:myViewController
                                         selector:@selector(NotificationReceived:)
                                             name:@"notification"
                                           object:nil];
```

And remember to un-register observer before the observer is deallocated, else your app will [crash](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Articles/Registering.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000723-98846)

Or in Swift 3:

```swift
let myViewController = UIViewController()
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    myViewController,
    selector: #selector(NotificationReceived),
    name: Notification.Name("notification"),
    object: nil)
```

Comment: but the system is supposed to create that instance for me, since it is a viewcontroller

Comment: @LenaBru ??? no, this statement makes no sense. There is nothing special about viewControllers, like all other classes you must create an instance

Comment: if i create an instance at registration of notification, i do not receive the notification..... in the class i need at runtime

Comment: what if the selector you want to call belongs to the outside class? what do you as selector parameter?

Answer (score 2):

For Posting notification:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"notificationName" object:nil];
```

For adding observer in any view:

```
 // Add observer
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(yourmethod) name:@"notificationName" object:nil];
```